# upper bound on the smallest modulus for perfect hashing of a Huffman tree

Tags: binary-trees, hashing, huffman-coding, modular-arithmetic, upper-bound

Given a [full binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees) with 256 leaves and depth <= 64,

- let `H` be the set of [Huffman codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) described by the tree (using 0 to go left, and 1 to go right, where the most significant bit represents the move from the root node

  - e.g. "100" means that starting from the root, we head right, then left, then left
- transform `H` into set `G` by right-padding each member of the set with zeroes so that the length of the binary string is 64, then interpreting that binary string as an unsigned integer

  - e.g. "1101" turns into 0xd000000000000000
- let M be the smallest positive integer where every element in `G` modulo `M` is distinct

  - i.e if `a` and `b` are members of `G`, `a % M != b % M`

What's the largest `M` among all such trees?

So far, the largest I've found by random search is 4493 (which happens to be a prime number). With 256 leaves, an exhaustive search of all trees is not computationally feasible. Through my experiments (using random tree generation), the upper bound on `M` seems to increase monotonically with the number of leaves.

A concrete value for the specific case of 256 leaves is all I need at the moment, but of course a more generalised solution would be awesome!

Comment: A related problem, which might be easier to solve, is to let G be a set of 256 arbitrary non-negative integers (i.e ignore the Huffman code constraint).

Comment: Edit to previous comment (which I can no longer edit): 256 arbitrary _64-bit_ unsigned integers.